# Restrict return classes in Apache CXF

Tags: java, security, cxf

Is it possible to make sure that CXF will not release a class?  I am fairly sure that my program wont at present but would want to be certain.

Basically I have a `User` class that is used a lot around the internal server side but whenever it is released to the client side I want to only release a `CleanUser` class object.

I am happy with a runtime error but would obviously prefer compile time!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use only [DTOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) in WS layer.
2. Prefer *contract first* (from WSDL) development.